# HTML Page Builder in Umbraco

Tags: html, umbraco, builder, rich-text-editor

I am trying to implement web page builder in **Umbraco**. I am currently using **tinyMCE** rich text editor but it has very limited features and some of the features doesn't work. In tinyMCE fontSize, fontColor and fontFamily are not working for me.

I want to add additional features also like adding background image, setting font styles, adding custom css and javascripts .
If there are some other editors or Umbraco package that provide features as per my requirements then it will also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/config/tinymceconfig/

Comment: Yes.. But it still missing some features like background image, adding facility to integrate custom css and JS etc.. What can be the alternate??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the Grid property editor as an alternative to the TineMCE Rich Text Editor.

It allows for layout, styling, and more of a component-based page building mechanism.

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout/